# How to add arguments for microsoft edge using selenium==4.10.0 and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import EdgeOptions


profile_directory = r'C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data'

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + profile_directory)
edge_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r"C:\Drivers\msedgedriver.exe", options=edge_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

For the above code getting from

```
selenium.webdriver.edge.options import EdgeOptions
ImportError: cannot import name 'EdgeOptions' from 'selenium.webdriver.edge.options'
```

How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in below line:

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import EdgeOptions
```

`EdgeOptions` has been removed in Selenium and instead you should use `Options`. So change the code to:

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options as EdgeOptions
```

Having said that, with the latest selenium `v4.10.0`, you don't really have to worry about setting the path for `driver.exe`. `Selenium Manager` module within the latest selenium will take care of browsers and browser drivers.

Code can be as simple as:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Edge()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options as EdgeOptions
```

[source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk//examples/python/tests/browsers/test_edge.py#L6-L7)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options as EdgeOptions

options = EdgeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
```